# How do I find name of sub directory which does not have any files containing string with shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a parent folder consist of many children sub-directories. In each sub-directory, there are(is) several config file(s).

```
Parent
  |-ChildA - (conf1.yaml, conf2.yaml, foo.yaml)
  |-ChildB - (bar.yaml)
  |-ChildC - (conf2.yaml, foo.yaml, bar.yaml)
  |-ChildD - // if there is GrandChild directory, there is no file.
      |-GrandChildA - (confA.yaml, conf1.yml, foo.yml)
      |-GrandChildB - (confB.yaml, bar.yml)
      |-GrandChildC - (hello.yaml, conf5.yml, foo.yml)
      |-GrandChildD - (world.yaml, conf10.yml)
  |-ChildE - (conf1.yaml, conf2.yaml)
  ....
```

Even if names of yaml files are same, contents may be different. I want to find out the name of directory which does not contain the string pattern in yaml file.
For example, I am looking for the string pattern, `overflow` and `ChildA/conf1.yaml` and `GrandChildC/hell.yaml` contains this string pattern, then I want to have output,

```
ChildB, ChildC, GrandChildA, GrandChildB, GrandChildD, ChildE // don't mind its format, array, json
```

I was thinking to use `grep` with its option, but it returns, name of file, not name of directory. How can I get name of directory which does not have any files containing pattern string?

EDIT
I think my explanation was kinda unclear. My ultimate goal is,

- If any file in the directory contains pattern, do not print out directory name
- If all files in the directory do not contains the pattern string, then print out directory name

Comment: Something like: `grep -rL overflow * | xargs dirname | uniq`?

Comment: @kaylum I tried, but it still prints out the name of directory if there is any file contains pattern string

Answer (score 0):

```
(
  # list of possible directories
  find Parent -type f -name '*.yaml' -print0 |\
  xargs -0 dirname |\
  sort | uniq

  # list of unwanted directories (may contain duplicates)
  find Parent -type f -name '*.yaml' -print0 |\
  xargs -0 grep -l overflow |\
  xargs -r dirname

  # uniq -u will remove anything that appears in both lists
) | sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: I tried this, 1)created shell script file 2)terminal and got xargs: permission denied. I changed my folder to 770 and also used sudo, but still get permission denied

Comment: check for typos. ensure no whitespace after backslashes. Are you sure error was `xargs: permission denied` exactly? I would expect  `xargs: program-name: Permission denied` for some value of `program-name`

Comment: don't run random scripts you get off the internet that you don't understand under `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU tools for their null delimiter flags (so that filenames containing new lines won't break it).

```
# find .yaml files containing "mypattern"
find /parent/dir -type f -name '*.yaml' -exec grep -Zl mypattern {} + |

# get parent dir names of matching files
xargs -0 -- dirname -z -- |
sort -zu |

# compare this list against all dirs, printing non matches
grep -Fvxzf - <(find /parent/dir -type d -print0)
```

- Final output is new line delimited, add `-Z` to the last grep for null delimited output. In GNU grep, `-z` = null delimited input, `-Z` null delimited output.
- You could replace second find with `find /parent/dir -type f -name '*.yaml' -exec dirname -z -- {} + | sort -zu` to only compare dirs which actually contain yaml files.
- ie. list those *containing* yaml, but *not* yaml which has `mypattern`; as opposed to listing *every* dir which doesn't have yaml containining `mystring` (basically: don't list dirs containing no yaml files at all).
- Hope that makes sense.